# System.console() is null

Tags: java, nashorn

Today is the first day playing with Nashorn.. I'm trying to listen to input from console.readLine(). Unfortunately it returns null. What am I doing wrong?

```
var Console = Packages.java.io.Console;
var Level = Packages.java.util.logging.Level;
var Logger = Packages.java.util.logging.Logger;
var System = Packages.java.lang.System;
var Thread = Packages.java.lang.Thread;
function onStart() {
    new Thread(function () {
        var logger = Logger.getLogger("com.TestClass");
        var console = System.console();
        if(console != null){
            logger.info("Exists!");
            while(true) {
                var input = console.readLine();
                logger.warning(input);
            }
        } else {
            logger.warning("Does not exist!");
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Which system are you running on? It returns `null` if there is no console attached to the JVM.

Comment: Note that Nashorn is deprecated since Java 11. Consider using better alternatives (see [JEP 335](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335)).

Comment: It's for an extension on a server mod. Guess I'm going to have to do it a different way. Thanks anyways

Comment: ... or you just attach a console to your JVM ^^